# Adding fields to an options page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to add fields to an options page through PHP, and I can't get it to work, I've tried nearly everything by now, but it just won't work.

I hope you can help, my php looks like this:

```
if (function_exists('acf_add_options_page')) {
    $option_page = acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title' => 'Indstillinger',
        'menu_title' => 'Indstillinger',
        'menu_slug' => 'options',
        'capability' => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect' => false
    ));
}

function my_acf_add_local_field_groups() {

    acf_add_local_field_group(array(
        'key' => 'group_1',
        'title' => 'My Group',
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'field_1',
                'label' => 'Sub Title',
                'name' => 'sub_title',
                'type' => 'text',
            )
        ),
        'location' => array(
            array(
                array(
                    'param' => 'post_type',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => 'options',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
}

add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_add_local_field_groups');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can just add them in the wordpress end after this going to tools and do export to php. and then delete from the wordpress.

Comment: Oh thanks. Will try that!

Answer (score 3):

I have found out.

```
'location' => array(
       array(
            array(
                'param' => 'options_page',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'theme-general-settings',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Here in the value field just add the "menu slug" that you have registered for the options page. Like 'theme-header-settings', 'theme-general-settings' are you requirement. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'options_page',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'options',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have added Option page, it seems that you have installed ACF plugin.

You can add any type of field on your option page using ACF plugin as well.

Check my attached screen shot, You need to set following condition for the field groups:

[image]